# Why are some properties and methods available in Powershell but not C#

Tags: c#, powershell

The following all work perfectly in PowerShell, but they can't even compile in C# in Visual Studio:

```
D:\> $dow = [DayOfWeek]'Monday'
D:\> $dow.ToInt32($null)
1
D:\> $dow.value__
1
```

Why is this so?

Thanks.

Comment: The answers are valid - still you can check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek.aspx which can probably help you

Answer (score 3):

Because PowerShell and C# are completely different systems.

C# is a strongly-typed compiled language and PowerShell is a scripting language. Just like C# is different from VBA, it is different from PowerShell, which in turn is also different from VBA.

So each has unique features, some are the same in different environments must most features are not.

Comment: That doesn't mean it supports the same features or shares any syntax rules.

Comment: true, but in this case I'm pretty sure it's because enums *do* implement a ToInt32 method, which any .NET language can call; this is not specific to PowerShell. The fact that it's directly accessible in PS, though, is probably specific to PS (other languages don't allow to call methods of explicitly implemented interfaces directly)

Comment: *"So each has unique features, some are the same in different environments must most features are not."*

Comment: I second Thomas Levesque.  The same property of the same CLR object should be available in both.  I don't think it is a syntax issue in this case.

Comment: @OldGeezer They are, but in different forms: eg. `Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), "Monday")`. In this example PSH knowns how to use `Parse` for enumerated types.

Comment: @Richard, thanks. You are right about the first statement.  But the second and third statements look like straightforward access of a CLR object's method and property, ie it works for other methods/properties.  The PSH name for the property is unusual though.  The property is not Value but value__.  Many PSH CLR objects have similar names for properties.  I suspect those cannot be accessed in C# too.

Comment: @OldGeezer 2nd is `((IConvertable)dow).ToInt32(null)` (`enum` implicitly implements `IConvertable` and not supplying a `IFormatProvider` defaults to the thread's default culture). 3rd is the implementation of enum types (take a look at the fields of an enum types in a decompiler); but most tools (including the C# compiler and VS) hide this.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is this is because all enums implement `IConvertible`. In C# the [`ToInt32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb468863.aspx) method is not directly visible because the interface is implemented explicitly, but Powershell probably has different rules.

Answer (score 2):

For the most part C# is a statically typed langauge while PowerShell is mostly dynamically typed. Basically that means that type checking is done at compile time in C# (excluding dynamic code blocks) and type checking is done at runtime in PowerShell.

C# also has type safety which prevents you treating a value of one type as a value of another type. Hence you will get a compile error.